# Dimension of the image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0& *& *\\
0 &0& *& *\\
0 &0& 0& *\\
0 &0& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
(* denotes a non-zero element)

If $A$ is considered as a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^4$, what is the dimension of $Image(A)$ and $Image(A^2)$

By observation I think that dimension of $Image(A)$ and $Image(A^2)$ are 2 and 1 respectively. I observe the columns and how the basis elements are mapped. Is this answer correct?

Comment: @John they are strictly non-zero

Comment: Yes, the answer should be correct.

Comment: how to explain the answer @G.Sassatelli

Comment: I thought he already had an argument for that and wanted to know whether he was right or not... but ok. $$$$ $\text{rk} A=2$ because $Ae_3,\ Ae_4$ are obviously independent and $\dim\ker A\ge 2$ $$$$  $\text{rk} A^2=1$ because $A^2e_1=A^2e_2=A^2e_3=0$ and $A^2e_4=A(c_1e_1+c_2e_2+c_3e_3)=b_1c_3\cdot e_1+b_2c_3\cdot e_2\neq 0$ $$$$ All these can be proved using $*\neq 0$ $$$$ @learnmore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension of the image of a matrix when regarded as a linear map is its rank.
So if $*$ denotes a non zero element then the last column of $A$ is not a multplite of the third since it has a $*$ in the third place and the third column has a zero. Hence they are linearly independent hence rank of $A$ is 2. Here is $A^2$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & * \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & * \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

so rank $A^2$ is 1 hence dimension of image of $A^2$ is indeed 1.